# Are the tiles and custom views in OMS dashboard updated periodically whenever there is new telemetry available?

Tags: azure, logging, analytics, oms

How frequently are the tiles and custom views in OMS workspace updated with new data? Also is it something that we can configure? Our customer wants to look at the most recent data (few minutes delay is also acceptable) even though there will be alerts configured for most of the scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working with test data, so the auto update feature of the tiles when minutes are passing, is an answer I cannot give at this moment. But they should be auto updating.

The time span is a setting which is called the time scope. You can set this up how you like. Setup in minutes, hour and days.

The tiles are built based on queries, the aggregations, grouping and intervals are also features you can make use of it.

The tiles are giving a global info, when you click on it, another page is being openend where you can develop a report like insight.

Comment: Yes, I agree that we can use time based queries but that will represent the tile using result set acquired at the time tge query was executed. But once the tile is rendered, it doesn't refresh the rest set periodically. We are using browser plugins to automatically refresh the page.